# Converting Objective-C to Swift Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyLow, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];

self.faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];
```

Please help me to convert this into swift.

I referred this code from iCapps.
I have only learned Swift. I tried to understated the code, but its bit confusing.
Please help me if any experts knows. And suggest me some ideas to convert Obj-C to Swift easily.

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: Next time, search "(class name) class reference" and read the documentation. It's available in both Objective-C and Swift, so you can see how to convert between them.

Comment: Vow, Thats really helpful @Arc676 !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let detectorOptions = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow]
self.faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: detectorOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code:

```
var detectorOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyLow
]

self.faceDetector = CIDetector.detectorOfType(CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: detectorOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted it for you, but now onwards use this site [https://objectivec2swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code) for conversion if you don't know swift

```
var detectorOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyLow
]
self.faceDetector = CIDetector.detectorOfType(CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: detectorOptions)
```